# Ensure unique input is entered and stored in an array

Tags: c++

Is this program OK, or can it be improved (but simply)? How do I make sure no repeat numbers are entered?

```
int n;
int array[9];

cout<<"Enter Number Between 9-0 Only"<<endl;
for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){
    cout<<"Enter Number" <<(i+1)<<endl;
    cin >> n;
    if((n >= 0) && (n <=9)){
       array[i]=n;
     }
        else{
        cout<<"Numbers from 0-9 only\n"<<endl;

        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: This program does not even attempt to check for repeated numbers. Hint: you need a nested loop.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add the homework tag. You'll still get help though. :)

Comment: its not homework im doing this for parts... im working on the repeating part.. but need to know if this can be improve or is there any way i can incorporate all in one step etc

Comment: The one step approach definitely is `std::set` (especially if you need them sorted still), which is basically just a special type of array. It doesn't have to be as robust as my other example. Just modify your program here to use a set instead of an array and keep in mind that duplicates being added will be ignored. With that in mind, it takes minimal change to the code here (just implementing Jack's answer, really). The only other thing to watch out for is that you can't access elements of a set with `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(edit) complete, compiling code

To check if the numbers are used with higher performance, try something like this (using the working code from Jack Radcliffe):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n = 0;
  int array[9] = {0};

  bool isUsed[10] = {0};

  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
  {
    cout << "Enter Number " << (i + 1) << endl;
    cin >> n;

    if((n >= 0) && (n <= 9))
    {
      if (isUsed[n] == false)
      {
        array[i] = n;
        isUsed[n] = true;
      }

      else
      {
        cout << "Number has already been used." << endl;
        i--;
      }
    }

    else 
    {
      cout << "Numbers from 0-9 only." << endl;
      i--;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Optimization isn't exactly necessary with this simple of code, but it's this seems to be an exercise of practice, so why not practice optimized code, too?

Answer (score 0):

Most of it is fine, though there are two problems standing out.

First, you have an array of size 9, but you are taking in 11 numbers since you're starting the for loop at 0 and going through to 10.

Second, since you have it so if the entered number is not between 0 and 9, inclusive, the for loop breaks.  This entails that fewer than 9 numbers will be put into the array if an invalid number is entered.  Change the entire loop to read this and you should be good:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    cout << "Enter Number " << (i + 1) << endl;
    cin >> n;
    if((n >= 0) && (n <= 9))
       array[i] = n;
    else {
        cout << "Numbers from 0-9 only\n" << endl;
        i--;
    }
}
```

The whole fire part was right, but I removed the break in the else-statement and added in the i--.  I added that in so when the user is prompted to re-enter the number, the entry number will be at the correct index.

I hope this was helpful.